# How to have multiple exposed filters in a block that affects multiple views content panes in a panel?

Tags: 7, views, panels

I have a view with multiple content panes. One shows a table, other shows a chart and so on. On every content pane I have the same exposed filters and it's exposed as a block.

In a panel I add all thosse content panes and on top of the page I show the exposed block. How can I make the filter to affect all the content panes and not one individually?

Comment: drupal version?

Comment: Sorry. It's Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Select one of your displays (lets say table1) and add (or recreate) the other displays as attachments.  Then only display table1 on your page and all other displays should tag along with it. Then expose the filter for table1.

Here's a good overview:
http://nmc-codes.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/views-attachment-in-drupal-7.html

**UPDATE:**

If you just want disconnected views to pick up on one exposed filter then this might do the trick:
https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter

It gives you configurable blocks with filter options. These options are made available as contextual filters so your views don't need to have the exposed filters.

Comment: Thanks Japo. Will take a look. Wonder if it works with Ajax, that was one of the issues I had.

Comment: It should since it acts as one whole view. :) good luck!

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for my scenario. In your solution I always have attached views and I don't want that. I need individual panes so that I can put them in Panels.

Comment: updated. But mind you it is 'picked once, operates site-wide'